# Test for relevance of the "copyright" tag

Tags: discussion, tags

I noted there has been some opposition to me applying the "copyright" tag to [this question](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/96097/does-one-need-the-prototypes-permission-to-make-dolls).

Do we consider it relevant only when it legally applies to the subject?

Or do we also consider it relevant where people generally are likely to believe that it applies, and only those enlightened know that it does not?

If the former rule applies, then I guess we should remove the tag from questions about ideas, like [this](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/18530/how-to-protect-my-idea-by-copyright) for example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the question about ideas, the question is "how to protect my idea by copyright." Thus, it *is* a question about copyright, albeit based on a flawed premise. It fits within the copyright tag.

In the question about personality or publicity rights, nothing in the question text raises the issue of copyright at all. Therefore, there it does not fit within the copyright tag.

Had it asked *whether* copyright applies, then it would have fit within the copyright tag.

What matters is what the question is in fact asking about, not what visitors' conceptions might be.

See https://law.stackexchange.com/help/tagging